# Does MultiBit Classic assign a password or is it manually set?

Tags: multibit

I have a MultiBit Classic wallet that I have had since 08/2014 and for the life of me I can not remember the password, I honestly don't even remember putting a password on it at the time.
My question is, would MultiBit assign a password automatically once bitcoins have been deposited into it?
I am stuck and I have tried every password that I could think of that I may have used.
Any help greatly appreciated
Cheers